# If and If else statement problems

Tags: r, if-statement, sum

Can anyone give me a hint as to how I can appropriately assign the votes to each candidate using the if and if-else statement? The commands below are counting the entire sum of the votes and I can't seem to figure out how to make R separate the votes for each candidate (Trump and Biden). Sorry for such a newbie question...

```
# Read CSV file    
results <- read.csv("PRESIDENT_precinct_primary.csv")
View(results)
    
# Votes set to zero
Trump <- 0
Biden <- 0
n <- length(results)
    
    
for(i in 1:n){
if(results$candidate[i] == "DONALD J TRUMP"){
Trump <- sum(results$votes[i])
}
else if(results$candidate[i] == "JOSEPH R BIDEN"){
Biden <- sum(results$votes[i])
}
else{}
    }
# Final Results
cat("Trump:", Trump)
cat("Biden:", Biden)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issue is in the value of 'n'.  It should be `nrow` of 'results' and not the `length` as the `length` is same as number of columns (`ncol`) in a `data.frame` (`read.csv` returns a `data.frame`)

```
n <- nrow(results)
```

so that when we loop over `1:n` and extract `results$candidate[i]`, it extracts each element of the column 'candidate'

Next, issue is how we are getting the `sum` and assigning.  The 'Trump' and 'Biden' are objects created inside the loop and it is getting updated in each iteration while the `sum` is not doing anything as there is only a single element (`results$votes[i]`).  Instead, we may need to a `compound assignment` operation i.e. add (`+`) and assign to the same object (`R` doesn't have the compound assignment operator `+=`)

```
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
    if(results$candidate[i] == "DONALD J TRUMP") {
        Trump <- Trump + results$votes[i]
     } else if(results$candidate[i] == "JOSEPH R BIDEN") {
         Biden <- Biden + results$votes[i]
       
        }
    }
```

---

In `R`, these are just vectorized operations and we can do this without any loop

```
Trump <- with(results, sum(votes[candidate == "DONALD J TRUMP"]))
Biden <- with(results, sum(votes[candidate == "JOSEPH R BIDEN"]))
```

Or more easily, it is a grouping operation

```
aggregate(votes ~ candidate, results, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: Nice! Yes, that one finally worked. It took me about 2 hours to get this far and got stuck here. One more question, what role does the command seq_len(n) play here? Is it to read off each row in sequence?

Comment: @ANG It is just if you have a data.frame with 0 rows `1:n` returns `[1] 1 0` while `seq_len(0)#
integer(0)`.  So, I would consider `seq_len` a bit less buggy

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the question. If you want to separate votes you can do this :

```
Biden = results[results$candidate == "JOSEPH R BIDEN", ]
```

Same for Trump.

If you want to do the same as you did in another way.

```
library(dplyr)
results %>% group_by(candidate) %>%
 summarize(votes = sum(votes))
```